# Line and text with canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I've a noob question about android dev.

I search how to draw a line with a text on it.

I visited a lot of website talking about it but no one answer me.

i've created this function :

```
private void creerLigne(float x, float y, float xend, float yend, int color) {

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    mImage.draw(c);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(color);
    p.setTextSize(50);   

    Path path = new Path();

    path.moveTo(x - xend, y - yend);



    c.drawTextOnPath("42", path, 0,30,p);
    c.drawLine(x, y, xend, yend, p);
    mImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

With this, i've a line and the text but the text is in the top left hand corner :( .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried..  **canvas.drawText("Text to be draw", txt_x_position, txt_y_position, paint);**

Comment: where do you want your text to be?

Comment: i want my text at the center of the line. And i've not use drawText just drawTextOnPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates `x, y, xend, yend` are all absolute positions within the image, right?

In this case the Path should be build as:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(x,y);
path.lineTo(xend, yend);
c.drawTextOnPath("42", 0, 30, path, p); // baseline is 30 pixel above the path
```

In the Paint you can also set flags to ensure the text is centered along the path with `p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER)`

Comment: THANKS!!!!!! It's exactly what i want jboi!!! so powerfull :D. But one thing, when the line is vertical, can i have the text in horizontal?

Comment: It feels good to help. That's why I'm here at Stackoverflow. The text follows your Path, no matter where the path goes. You can give it a try, but I expect that all letters are upwards, means that on a vertical line each letter is below its predecessing letter. I'd rotate text once, and I'd put the text into a bitmap and rotated it  by applying a matrix. Just make sure the bitmap is large enough to keep the unrotated and the rotated text. After rotating you place the rotated text into a larger bitmap with `Canvas.drawBitmap()`